# Symfony - Circular reference detected only only cache-clear prod

Tags: php, symfony

somethings is weird with my cache:clear : in dev environment there's no error but if I did with cache:clear --env=prod , I've got a "**Circular reference detected for service**".

What's wrong ?

Copy of the stacktrace :

```
Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2235
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/                                             Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ManagerRegistry.php:35
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry->getService() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/D                                             octrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php:183
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getManager() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/lexik/tra                                             nslation-bundle/Lexik/Bundle/TranslationBundle/Storage/AbstractDoctrineStorage.php:48
 Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Storage\AbstractDoctrineStorage->getManager() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendo                                             r/lexik/translation-bundle/Lexik/Bundle/TranslationBundle/Storage/DoctrineORMStorage.php:19
 Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Storage\DoctrineORMStorage->translationsTablesExist() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfo                                             ny/vendor/lexik/translation-bundle/Lexik/Bundle/TranslationBundle/EventDispatcher/GetDatabaseResourcesListener.php:                                             41
 Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\EventDispatcher\GetDatabaseResourcesListener->onGetDatabaseResources() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Even                                             tDispatcher.php:184
 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/sym                                             fony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:46
 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/lexik/transla                                             tion-bundle/Lexik/Bundle/TranslationBundle/Translation/Translator.php:28
 Lexik\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Translation\Translator->addDatabaseResources() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/                                             cache/pro_/appProdProjectContaine_.php:3871
 appProdProjectContaine_->getLexikTranslation_TranslatorService() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/bootstrap.php                                             .cache:2261
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/cache/pro_/appProdProje                                             ctContaine_.php:7820
 appProdProjectContaine_->getTwigService() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2261
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/cache/pro_/appProdProje                                             ctContaine_.php:3908
 appProdProjectContaine_->getMailManagerService() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2261
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/cache/pro_/appProdProje                                             ctContaine_.php:2025
 appProdProjectContaine_->getFei_DoctrineListener_UserService() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.c                                             ache:2261
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/cache/pro_/appProdProje                                             ctContaine_.php:1235
 appProdProjectContaine_->getDoctrine_Dbal_DefaultConnectionService() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/bootstrap                                             .php.cache:2261
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/cache/pro_/appProdProje                                             ctContaine_.php:1349
 appProdProjectContaine_->getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/bootstr                                             ap.php.cache:2261
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/                                             Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ManagerRegistry.php:35
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry->getService() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/D                                             octrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php:231
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getManagers() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/                                             symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php:49
 Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer->warmUp() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/symf                                             ony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php:48
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/bootst                                             rap.php.cache:2775
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache                                             :2542
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bun                                             dle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:134
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->warmup() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/                                             symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:96
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony                                             /symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfon                                             y/Component/Console/Application.php:861
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/S                                             ymfony/Component/Console/Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/                                             Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:84
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony                                             /src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/nf-platform/symfony/app/console:27

cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--                                             ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <comman                                             d>
```

Comment: verify that you are really  using `--evvnv=prod` instead of  `--env=prod`

Comment: Sorry it was a typo only in my post, using the right synthax in my console ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with Symfony I find that in some cases the `cache:clear` command isn't enough. Sometimes I have to clear the cache completely at file system level. Use one of the following commands instead (assuming you're in a Unix like environment).

For Symfony 2.x:

`rm -rf ./app/cache/*`

For Symfony 3.x and 4.x:

`rm -rf ./var/cache/*`

*If you had any `.gitkeep` files in there you'll need to `touch` them again before committing.*

You should not need to run `cache:clear` again after doing this, as Symfony will warm up a brand new cache on your first application request. Expect your first request to take noticeably longer to process though. (10-20 seconds can be expected depending on your app.)

---

About the circular reference specifically I'd suggest you have two custom service classes both of which have the Symfony service container injected into them, then try to reference each other via `$this->container->get('the_other_service')->whatever();`.

As of Symfony 4.0 this is no longer supported, forcing you to use dependency injection instead. (Service classes should no longer have the service container injected into them, as tempting and easy as it may appear.) -- I know the struggle this can be particularly when upgrading from Symfony 2.x or 3.x, but we're told it's for the best.